# Database migration notnull()?

Tags: database-migration, laravel-5.4

I use migration to add nullable() to column.

```
class ChangeUgIdCanNull extends Migration
{
  public function up()
  {
    Schema::table('service_request_step', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->dropForeign(['ug_id']);
    });
    Schema::table('service_request_step', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->dropIndex(['ug_id']);
    });
    Schema::table('service_request_step', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->integer('ug_id')->unsigned()->index()->nullable()->change();
      $table->foreign('ug_id')->references('ug_id')
            ->on('user_group')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
  }

  public function down()
  {
    Schema::table('service_request_step', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->dropForeign(['ug_id']);
    });
    Schema::table('service_request_step', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->dropIndex(['ug_id']);
    });
    Schema::table('service_request_step', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->integer('ug_id')->unsigned()->index()->change();
      $table->foreign('ug_id')->references('ug_id')
            ->on('user_group')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
  }
}
```

When i use `php artisan migrate` is fine.
But, When I want to `php artisan migrate:rollback.` In my database in 'ug_id' column is still nullable.
Did I have some function like `$table->integer('ug_id')->unsigned()->index()->notnull()->change();`

```
Laravel Version: 5.4.19
PHP Version: 7.1.3
Database Driver & Version: 10.2.4-MariaDB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nullable(false)`. 
Your code should be

```
$table->integer('ug_id')->unsigned()->index()->nullable(false)->change();
```

Comment: Wowww. That is. Thank you.